# basic_string allocator

Tags: c++, reverse-engineering

i'm wondering what does this do:

```
std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>::
basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>
(&myText, "hello world");
```

my first guess is that it's allocating "hello world" to a `myText` variable
if that's true then what does it do in this case :

```
  if ( v106 == v67 || 
  std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>::
  basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>
  (&v109,"program"), v137 = 1)
  {
    BYTE3(v95) = 0;
  }
```

it's not really a condition...

Comment: Something about your code got mangled. This is not valid C++. Maybe you lost some linebreaks somewhere?

Comment: Where did you get this code from?\

Comment: What is `char_std`? That's a slightly rude way of asking for real code.

Comment: Calls of string constructor is incorrect really.

Comment: It should be clear from [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) that all that mess is available as the convenient but little known typedef `std::string`.

Comment: To OP, if I incorrectly edit your code - rollback changes and edit yourself. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess this is output from Hex-Ray's decompiler plugin for IDA, am I right? This is the way it displays the call of the constructor of the `std::string` class. `v109` is the memory allocated on the stack to hold the `std::string` instance, while the second parameter, `"hello world"`, is the string to initialize it with.

In cases where multiple conditions lead to the same resulting code, compilers often choose to reuse the (equivalent) code fragment from a previous condition to minimize the size of the generated bytecode. Hex-Ray's decompiler plugin often displays them using the [Comma-operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) up to version 1.5 - newer versions of the decompiler have [a better understanding of such situations](http://www.hex-rays.com/products/decompiler/v16_vs_v15.shtml#2).

```
if (v106 == v67)
    BYTE3(v95) = 0;

std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>,
                  std::allocator<char>>
                  ::basic_string<char, 
                      std::char_traits<char>, 
                      std::allocator<char>>(&v109,"program");
v137 = 1;
BYTE3(v95) = 0;
```

This is more likely to look like the actual source. Replacing the huge `std::basic_string<...>` construct with a simple `std::string` declaration makes it even more readable.

```
if (v106 == v67)
    BYTE3(v95) = 0;

std::string v109("program");
v137 = 1;
BYTE3(v95) = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks yeah that's what i thought, but in the "if" assigning a text to a variable is not a condition as far as i know..